# Django 404 css file

Tags: python, html, css, django, web-deployment

For a long time I tried to solve the problem with loading all my static files. When I found a working solution, all svg started loading, but css files didn't.

Here is my settings.py (showing you only main things)

```
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type("text/css", ".css", True)
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = False
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
if DEBUG: STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
else: STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url

from django.conf import settings

from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),       
]
```

Here is an example of using css files in my templates

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-v4-grid-only@1.0.0/dist/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {% static 'css/reset.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {% static 'css/main.css' %}">
```

And this is the error in Chrome Console

```
Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

And also i cant open css files in a new tab. I am getting that error
[image]

Also, if you remove %20 from the address bar, then I will open the css file

P.S.
I am trying to deploy it

Comment: Which django version are you using?

Comment: @SunderamDubey i am using 3.2.15

Answer (score 0):

1- Try to replace a slash forward path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {% static '/css/reset.css' %}">
```

2- whitenoise

```
pip install whitenoise
```

Then, set it to "MIDDLEWARE" in "settings.py". Finally, CSS is loaded successfully:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware", # Here
    # "whitenoise" will solve "MIME type" error then CSS is loaded successfully:
]
```

3- change your static URL like that:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: I did these steps (except the last one, nothing worked with it at all). Now the css files are there, I can view them from the chrome console, but they still don't work. Now there is an error 500 145 in the terminal, but it was 404. In the chrome console, it also writes about the Mime type error

Comment: ok, now i have code 304. But my css files still dont work due to Mime type error

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is that you put in a space in front of your static link

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {% static 'css/reset.css' %}">`

Try removing the space in front of {% so it will become

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/reset.css' %}">`

%20 is translated to a space character in URL's, so that why I think that's the issue